# How to fetch values from .yml config file using Erlang

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am New to Erlang and Ejabberd. I have one configuration file as ejabberd.yml and one Erlang file. In Erlang File I want to fetch values of configuration. My code is as follow :

ejabberd.yml

```
modules:
  mod_client_asterisk:
        server_asterisk: "localhost"
        port_asterisk: "5038"
        username: "admin"
        secret: "secret"
        message: "TEXT"
```

Erlang File

```
Server = gen_mod:get_module_opt(global, ?MODULE, server_asterisk,  fun(A) -> A end, localhost),
```

It gives me following Error :

```
[error] <0.39.0>@gen_mod:validate_opts:291 unknown option 'server_asterisk' for module 'mod_client_asterisk' will be likely ignored, available options are:
```

If someone can help me for this.

Comment: The error says there is some problem with option 'server_asterisk'. It means that till this option everything was fine. Check out what wrong with this option: it might be something specific for curtain version on Ejabbed.

Comment: Probably, this might help: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/616